# Styling navigation drawer with recyclerview material design

Tags: android

So I am using a `RecyclerView` in my `Drawerlayout` following **material design**.

What I want is when I pressed a particular item in the `RecyclerView` it's background color and text color will be highlighted in a way I wanted. However, when I click each item it becomes highlighted only on that particular moment and does not retain its state after the drawer has been closed. So how can I create a selector like **youtube** navigation drawer which retains its highlight property when selected. Thanks.

So this is my layout for each item in the `RecyclerView`:

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer_row_selector"
    >


        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/navIcon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:text="Sample Text"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/primaryColorDark"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/primaryColorDark"
        android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:activated="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: badly need this guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pesudo code to save the state of selection. The implementation depends on the data the adapter uses. In principal you need store the selection in a member (in my example `isActive`) and designate an id for the root view element of the row which needs highlighting and clicking.

```
class Item {
...
boolean isActive;    

}

class View extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 ImageView navIcon;
 TextView title;
 RelativeLayout root;

 public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
   ...
   root = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewByid(R.id.root);
 }
}

class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
  List<Item> items;

  ...
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

     Item item = items.get(position);
     holder.root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){             
           item.isActive = !item.isActive;        
     });
     if(item.isActive){
        holder.root.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
     }else{
        holder.root.setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent);
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: I will definitely try this. I will get back to you later. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: This basically do the trick. However, when I pressed another item the previous selected item retains its properties. So how can I handle that?

Comment: really needed your help.

Comment: I already solved it. I will mark this as the answer but at the same time I will post my approach here if somebody happens to have the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So this is my approach of solving the problem. I do it on onBindViewHolder of RecyclerView.Adapter.

This is my whole adapter class:

```
  public class NavDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

        List<NavDrawerItem> data = Collections.emptyList();
        List<MyViewHolder> holders = new ArrayList<MyViewHolder>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context context;

        public NavDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<NavDrawerItem> data) {
            this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void delete(int position) {
            data.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
//storing holders instance to an array
            holders.add(holder);
            return holder;
        }

        //Set the contents of different views of the row.
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
            holder.img.setImageResource(current.getIcon());
            holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(current.isShowNotify()){
                        current.setShowNotify(false);
                        holder.root.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    }else{
                        current.setShowNotify(true);
                        holder.root.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
//looping through MyViewHolder instances and removing the background color if not selected
                        for(int i= 0; i < holders.size(); i++){
                            if(i != position){
                                holders.get(i).root.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
           //Log.d("JC", "onBindViewHolder() position : " + position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView title;
            ImageView img;
            RelativeLayout root;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.navIcon);
                root = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.root);
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope this will help someone.